# Deployment angularjs Application on server

Tags: web-applications, deployment

I have developed a web application using angualrjs and MVC . this application is working fine at my local end but after deploying on server . angularjs is not working . I think server is unable to load angularjs library

Now i need help to eliminate this behavior of my web application.

For reference i am attaching an Image

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrUOC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I use firebase to deploy my Angular apps. It's free. 
https://firebase.google.com/